# How are quantum computers able to process certain tasks faster than regular computers?

Tags: quantum-computing

I've read posts everywhere and watched videos but still I don't understand one part of it. How are they able to process all these operations in parallel.

So based on the landscape example [here](http://www.dwavesys.com/quantum-computing).

How would a quantum computer be able to check all those areas at once rather than the traditional algorithm to check random areas or process through the entire landscape